# Saving the last three scores to file

Tags: python, file-writing

I have been given a task to create a program which will test the maths skills of a student. I have done task 1 and 2 which was to make the quiz then save it to file but now task 3, I have to now save the last 3 scores of the student which I'm really struggling with.

Here's my code:

```
print("Good job",name,"! You have finished the quiz") #congrats user for finnsihing quiz
print("You got" + str(score) + " /10 questions correct!") #gives user final score out of 10
class_name = "class 1.txt"    # creates a file under the name a user specifies
with open(class_name, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines.append("{name} : {score}\n".format(name=name, score=score))
    with open(class_name, "w") as f:  # re-opening as "w" will blank the file
        for line in sorted(lines):
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: open file, read all data, close file, change data, open file, write all data, close file - where do you have problem ?

Comment: `student_scores = student_scores[-3:]`

Comment: ok here a link to my task read task 3    http://web1.crypt.gloucs.sch.uk/ict/Resources/OCR%20GCSE%20COMPUTING/Controlled%20Assessment%20Tasks/A453CA2Jun15_104065.pdf